# How to check if <a href> element exist in a <div> element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the html code is like this:

```
<div class="AAA">Text of AAA<a href="......AAA/url">Display text of URL A</a></div>
<div class="BBB">Text of BBB<a href="......BBB/url">Display text of URL B</a></div>
<div class="CCC">Text of CCC</div>
<div class="DDD">Text of DDD</div>
```

I want to parse the text for all the div, while check if there is url exist, if yes then also extract it out and display in output

output like this:

```
Text of AAA
Display text of URL A
......AAA/url
Text of BBB
Display text of URL B
......BBB/url
Text of CCC
Text of DDD
```

i tried to nest the loop of find_all('a') within find_all('div') loop, but messed up my output

Comment: please, share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just easier to read, You can also use this to get expected output

```
divs = soup.find_all('div')
for div in divs:
  print(div.contents[0]) # Text of AAA
  link = div.find('a')
  if link:
    print(link.text) # Display text of URL A
    print(link['href']) # ......AAA/url
```

Comment: thanks. this one gives closest logic to what i want to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="AAA">Text of AAA<a href="......AAA/url">Display text of URL A</a></div>
<div class="BBB">Text of BBB<a href="......BBB/url">Display text of URL B</a></div>
<div class="CCC">Text of CCC</div>
<div class="DDD">Text of DDD</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for div in soup.findAll('div'):
    print(div.text)
    try:
        print(div.find('a').text)
        print(div.find('a')["href"])
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Output

```
Text of AAADisplay text of URL A
Display text of URL A
......AAA/url
Text of BBBDisplay text of URL B
Display text of URL B
......BBB/url
Text of CCC
Text of DDD
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what your code looks like, but the basic idea is something like this:

```
data = soup.findAll('div')
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print(a['href'])
        print(a.text)
```

will give you the URL and the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the `divs` and then print the elements of `soup.contents`:

```
s = """
<div class="AAA">Text of AAA<a href="......AAA/url">Display text of URL A</a> . 
</div>
<div class="BBB">Text of BBB<a href="......BBB/url">Display text of URL B</a> . 
</div>
<div class="CCC">Text of CCC</div>
<div class="DDD">Text of DDD</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
for _text, *_next in map(lambda x:x.contents, soup(s, 'html.parser').find_all('div')):
  print(_text)
  if _next:
    print(_next[0].text)
    print(_next[0]['href'])
```

Output:

```
Text of AAA
Display text of URL A
......AAA/url
Text of BBB
Display text of URL B
......BBB/url
Text of CCC
Text of DDD
```

Comment: i want the result return a list first as i need to use translate() before printing final output, any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, i worked out the solution

```
for h in ans_kin:
    links = ""
    link = h.find('a')
    if link:
        for l in link:
            links = h.text + link.get('href')
    else:
        links = h.text

    answer_kin.append(links)
```